# Microsoft Graph API assign participant role to online meeting

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using graph API to create an online meeting and everything works fine as expected, I have the meeting created and with the web URL and phone audio information returned properly. However, now I'm trying to see if I can pre-assign a participant role to whoever person might join, and I can't seem to find anything from the documentation.

I've tried to add attendee with the following code during the creation of the meeting, but it can't seem to recognize or match with either the email or full name of the when he/she joins the meeting.

```
        var mpi = new MeetingParticipantInfo()
        {
            Identity = new IdentitySet
            {
                User = new Identity
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DisplayName = displayName
                }
            },
            Upn = email,
            Role = role
        };
```

Is there anything I'm missing or is the pre-assign role even possible programmatically in Teams meeting?

Comment: I haven't heard about any such role or way you can use it with Graph API!!

Comment: The related class definition is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/meetingparticipants?view=graph-rest-1.0

If there is such a getter and setter for meeting participant, then what is the actual use case of setting it?

Comment: @Dev Will you be able to find out more from your connection ?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont see any set for this. Being said that you can submit this as a new feature request and submit it [Microsoft Uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359626). So that you can consider implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Participant role.

Under Participant section - like you mentioned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/meetingparticipants?view=graph-rest-1.0

There are 2 categories

1. attendees
2. organizer

You have two roles  under attendees - Presenter, attendees.

### To add a attendees to meeting :

Use `PATCH`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlinemeetings/<MEETING ID>
```

You will be able to get the meeting when you had created the online meeting invite.

**For Attendee Role:**

```
{"participants":{"attendees":[{"identity":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identitySet"},"upn":"<UPN>","role":"attendee"}]}}
```

**For Presenter Role :**

```
{"participants":{"attendees":[{"identity":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identitySet"},"upn":"<UPN>","role":"presenter"}]}}
```

**Organizer**

As far as I have You will not be able to change/add organizer when you use the 'me' endpoint.

Comment: I've tried that at the c# level when a meeting is created, however, it didn't do anything to the person when they join the meeting,  their role won't change or assign to the one that I've preset. Am I missing something when the role is being assigned? In my case, I use the person email address as the UPN when a role is assigned, and I make sure they join the meeting with the corresponding email.

What do you mean when you say created the online meeting invite?  Is that something I missed where I need to send the meeting invite somehow instead of giving the meeting web url to my participants?

Comment: Can you pls elaborate about the role ?  are you meaning presenter role/ assignee role ?

Comment: The above is the graph api - you can elaborate the code you use to create / update the meeting ?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the presenter and attendee role, and I'd like to see if I can preset one of the participant to have presenter role ahead of time. And I'm using graph api to create the meeting as well, which I don't have problem with creating the meeting itself, it's just I can't preset participant.

Comment: By default, every attendee can present, so the API won't allow you to set an attendee's role to `presenter` unless you also change `allowedPresenters` to `roleIsPresenter`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0#onlinemeetingpresenters-values